# Filter indexed column based on attribute filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have a model 'ModelA' with a has_many relation to 'ModelB'.

ModelB has a description:text column, and a day:interger column (0-6 for weekdays).

I am indexing columns from ModelB in ModelA, so I can search through ModelA.

Excerpt from index block in ModelA:

```
indexes model_bs.description, as: :model_b_description
has model_bs.day, as: :model_b_day
set_property field_weights: {
    model_b_description: 10
}
```

I would like to do `ModelA.search('some description')` but filter the returned results using model_b_day, ensuring the description I am searching is on a specific day (lets say `:model_b_day => 5`).

I can search using `with: { day: 5 }`, but this will return ModelB's that match the day column, not whether the description matches the search AND on that day.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I should note I am using thinking sphinx v2.0.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx has no concept of key/value pairs (hashes, dictionaries, whatever you wish to call them), so it does not know that a description is tied to a day within your ModelA index - it just has a bunch of descriptions mashed together into a single string, and a bunch of days as an array of integers for each ModelA record.

The better solution in this scenario is to search on ModelB instead:

```
define_index do
  indexes description
  has day
  set_property field_weights: {description: 10}
end
```

That way there *is* the relationship between the field and attribute (as it's a single value of each per record). You could also pull in ModelA data via the association (I'm guessing there's a matching `belongs_to :model_a` in ModelB).

Comment: It seems that the search is still returning ModelB's just as long as ModelB has a description on a certain day, not whether it has a description that matches the search for that day.